# [Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1'

Tags: django, odbc, pyodbc, unixodbc, sqlanywhere

When I run
`$ python manage.py inspectdb --database=mssql_database`

I have the following error

```
django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

but the file `libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1` is there.

```
$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini 
[ODBC]
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=/tmp/odbc.log

[FreeTDS]
Description=TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver=libtdsodbc.so
Setup=libtdsS.so
CPTimeout=
CPReuse=
UsageCount=2

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1
UsageCount=1



$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
odbcinst: symbol lookup error: odbcinst: undefined symbol: odbcinst_system_file_name


$ ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff545c4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9f85470000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9f85268000)
    libodbcinst.so.2 => /home/pd/sibp/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlanydb-1.0.11.dist-info/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f9f84fcc000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f9f84cf6000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f9f84aab000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9f84722000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9f84384000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9f8416c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9f83f4d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9f83b5c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9f85a80000)
    libdbtasks17_r.so => /home/pd/sibp/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlanydb-1.0.11.dist-info/lib64/libdbtasks17_r.so (0x00007f9f83912000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f9f836f8000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f9f834c6000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f9f832c2000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f9f830b7000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f9f82eb3000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f9f82c99000)
```

OS: `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`

I started fresh with clean system and I'm creating snapshots of my virtualbox now. This happens as a result of installing `SQL Anywhere Database Client`.
See [here](https://kcsharepoint.home.blog/2021/08/02/python-connect-to-sybase-sap-database-linux-based-os-only/). I need `SQL Anywhere Database Client` to work with `Sybase`. After finishing this installation I have the above error.

```
$ pip list
Package       Version
------------- -------
Django        1.8
django-pyodbc 1.1.3
pip           21.3.1
pyodbc        4.0.32
setuptools    59.6.0
sqlany-django 1.13
sqlanydb      1.0.11
wheel         0.37.1
```

Comment: At a command prompt run `ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1` and see if there are any dependencies that it cannot resolve.

Comment: @GordThompson This seems strange `libodbcinst.so.2`. It refers to my sybase project `sibp` (another django project using sybase database)

Comment: Does the Sybase driver mess with your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like [this](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/678#issuecomment-573385714)?

Comment: @GordThompson I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71054425/django-how-to-correctly-install-library-without-pip-in-venv-to-work-after-depl) for my sybase project to work. I realized now that this is probably the reason that one of my projects that work with mssql stopped working at this point, similarly as I can't connect with this question with yet another project. I'd like to possibly solve it somehow without reinstalling the system and having two virtual machines with Ubuntu (one for sybase project and one for mssql projects).

Comment: If the Sybase project and the MSSQL project(s) need different Apache configurations then I wouldn't be surprised if trying to get them to "play nicely" within the same Apache instance would be more trouble than it's worth. However, I haven't had to mess with Apache for many years so I don't really know what the current state of affairs might be in this regard.

Comment: Do you get the error if you do `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH= python manage.py inspectdb --database=mssql_database` ?

Comment: @GordThompson When I stop apache, I still get this error.

Comment: What is your system environment?

Comment: @cachius `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`

Comment: Try hacking `/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh` and after the two existing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` lines add a third one for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"`. That seems to fix the `isql` error for me, but I can't test the SQL Anywhere part.

Comment: @GordThompson I tried it, but the error is the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

While not a complete answer for this particular case, the following information may be helpful for others having difficulty using both sqlanydb (for SAP SQL Anywhere) and pyodbc (for Microsoft SQL Server) on the same machine.

The [SQL Anywhere setup instructions](https://kcsharepoint.home.blog/2021/08/02/python-connect-to-sybase-sap-database-linux-based-os-only/) cited in the question instruct us to

```
source "/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh"
```

in .bashrc. That script includes, in part

```sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY17/lib32:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY17/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

which prepends the `SQLANY17/` directories to any existing LD_LIBRARY_PATH. On a vanilla install of Xubuntu 20.04 there is no LD_LIBRARY_PATH defined, so the net result is

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64:/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib32:
```

That works fine for sqlanydb

```py
# any.py
import sqlanydb
# Initiate connection to the database
DB_PARAMS = {"HOST": "192.168.0.199",
         "USER": "dba",
         "PASSWORD":"sql",
         "DB":""}
conn = sqlanydb.connect(host=DB_PARAMS['HOST'], uid=DB_PARAMS['USER'], pwd=DB_PARAMS['PASSWORD'], dbn=DB_PARAMS['DB'])
# Instantiate cursor
curs = conn.cursor()
# Execute a query
curs.execute("SELECT 'success' as connection_status FROM SYS.DUMMY")
result = curs.fetchall()
print(result)
```

```
$ python3 any.py
[('success',)]
```

but it causes pyodbc to fail

```py
# pyo.py
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;"
    "Server=192.168.0.199;"
    "Database=test;"
    "UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH;"
)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
print(crsr.execute("SELECT 'success' AS connection_status").fetchall())
```

```
$ python3 pyo.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyo.py", line 3, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

If we add a third LD_LIBRARY_PATH tweak to sa_config.sh

```sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY17/lib32:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY17/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and restart the machine to apply the changes then `any.py` (above) continues to work, but `pyo.py` (above, unmodified) works, too:

```
$ python3 pyo.py 
[('success', )]
```

Comment: I'm giving it a bounty, but I can test on monday if restart helps (I have problem with VPN now). If restart won't help, I will start another bounty.

Comment: So, for me, after restart it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have driver issue, run the following command and it should work

```
sudo apt-get install tdsodbc
```

update content of odbcinst.ini

```
$ sudo nano /etc/odbcinst.ini 
  [FreeTDS]
  Description = TDS Driver for MSSQL
  driver = path/to/libtdsodbc.so
  setup =  path/to/libtdsS.so
```

**[EDIT]**

Kindly share output after running this

```
  import pyodbc
  print(pyodbc.drivers())
```

Also kindly check if followed all steps here for target OS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: after `sudo apt-get install tdsodbc`
It ends with error `'01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'libtdsodbc.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

Comment: `$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
odbcinst: symbol lookup error: odbcinst: undefined symbol: odbcinst_system_file_name
`

Comment: Dear provide full path for (libtdsodbc.so ) ( libtdsS.so) in /etc/odbcinst.ini  and see if that works.

Comment: Full path doesn't work either.

Comment: It is very hard to debug the issue from here given the information. Kindly note, I am trying to be helpful not rude. But please follow the driver instlallation from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Also kindly try pyodbc.drivers() it should return list of drivers. If not there was miss step in setup or configuraiton.

Comment: The driver is installed.

Comment: Kindly check my edit...

Comment: In initial state pyodbc.drivers() showed two drivers installed as you can see them in the output of `/etc/odbcinst.ini`. Now the situation is different, because I tried to compile unixodbc and it didn't helped and after `apt-get install unixodbc` I have now broken packages. I'm trying another virtual machine now . Maybe I will get into this state again. But now I'm using snapshots, so will save machine state before this problem occurs. This need really troubleshooting of expert user. It's not so easy.

Comment: If you're interested you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72125405/odbcinst-symbol-lookup-error-odbcinst-undefined-symbol-odbcinst-system-file) subproblem.