# Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist

Tags: django, pyodbc, freetds, django-pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to `mssql` server via `FreeTDS`.

First I tried it via `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` and it works. Here is my configuration in `settings.py`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'mssql_database': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'blabla', 
        'USER': 'blabla', 
        'PASSWORD': 'blabla', 
        'HOST': '10.65.1.20', 
        'PORT': '',  
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', 
        },
    },
   
}
```

According to [this](https://www.tivix.com/blog/getting-django-working-with-mssql-pyodbc) guide I installed `FreeTDS` on `Ubuntu 18.04`.

Here is my `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1
UsageCount=1


[FreeTDS]
    Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
    Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
    Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
    CPTimeout =
    CPReuse =
```

And here is the new `settings.py` section

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'mssql_database': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'blabla', 
        'USER': 'blabla',  
        'PASSWORD': 'blabla', 
        'HOST': '10.65.1.20', 
        'PORT': '', 
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'FreeTDS', 
            'host_is_server': True,
            'extra_params': "TDS_VERSION=8.0"
        },
    },
}
```

And I have this error message
`pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (20009) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

How can I fix the error? The connection works with `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`. So why doesn't it work with `FreeTDS` driver? Could it be because the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so` isn't there? I can't find `libtdsS.so`.

```
$ pip list
Package       Version
------------- -------
Django        1.8
django-pyodbc 1.1.3
pip           21.3.1
pyodbc        4.0.32
setuptools    59.6.0
sqlany-django 1.13
sqlanydb      1.0.11
wheel         0.37.1
```

Comment: I set the port to `1433` and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, set the `PORT` to `1433` - but that is only part of what you need to do.

`TDS_Version=8.0` is invalid and **will** break on newer versions of FreeTDS greater than 1.3: https://www.freetds.org/userguide/ChoosingTdsProtocol.html

Since Ubuntu 18 ships with FreeTDS version 1.00.82, you should use version 7.4 of the TDS protocol, assuming you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher.

Change your options as follows:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'driver': 'FreeTDS', 
    'host_is_server': True,
    'extra_params': "TDS_Version=7.4"
},
```

You may have to re-run your migrations, if any, because the newer TDS Versions support more SQL Server fields, such as `DATE` and `DATETIME2` - but it looks like you may just be using SQL Server for reads. Good luck!

Comment: Tommorrow I wil start anew. Which Ubuntu packages should I install to have the FreeTDS version 7.4? Can I check my version somehow? Or should I compile the FreeTDS from source rather? But now, I won't use it with MSSQL Server, but Sybase as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72255279/freetdssql-serversql-anywhere-error-265-procedure-serverproperty-not-fou)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never heard of Django working with Sybase. I've helped out with the SQL Server backends for a few years, and recommend trying the Microsoft developed backend: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django For FreeTDS, you should be fine using whatever version modern Ubuntu supports. 18, 20, and 22 all support TDS Protocol 7.4, which AFAIK, is the most recent.

Comment: I will use it with `pyodbc` and `FreeTDS` with raw queries as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72259266/653379), because django does not work with `sybase`. Only Django to version 1.8 works with sqlanydb and sqlanydjango, but it causes that `pyodbc` stops [working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72125696/driver-managercant-open-lib-opt-microsoft-msodbcsql17-lib64-libmsodbcsql-17).

Comment: I installed unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-dev freetds-bin tdsodbc and when I run `tsql -C` there is a line `Version: freetds v1.00.82` and a line  `TDS version: 4.2`

Comment: That’s just the default TDS version. You can override it to 7.4 in version 1.0 and above.

Comment: OK, I understood.